# HTML download file with snapchat browser failed

Tags: html

Is it possible to download files over snapchat browser?
Tried with this code and seems not to work...

```
<a href="/downloads/tzm.pdf" target="_new"><img src="download.png" width="280px"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

For you to download files through Snapchat your device needs to have the correct and compatible software.

Comment: Tried now on an android device and seem's also not to work.. Isn't there a way to open it in default browser?